# Xamarin Forms - Sliding menu (navigation drawer) RTL mode

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to find a good implementation of Sliding menu for Xamarin Forms in RTL mode.
does anyone familiar with one ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this
http://www.telerik.com/xamarin-ui/sidedrawer
But it's expensive!

Answer (score 0):

SlideOverKit is a premium component for Xamarin.Forms. It allows developers to easily create awesome Slideovers in Xamarin.Forms.

https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit

Answer (score 0):

Make Custom Render For Master Detail Page in Android and add below code

```
public class MyMasterDetailPageRenderer : MasterDetailPageRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElement oldElement, VisualElement newElement)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(oldElement, newElement);
        var fieldInfo = GetType().BaseType.GetField("_masterLayout", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var _masterLayout = (ViewGroup)fieldInfo.GetValue(this);
        var lp = new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(_masterLayout.LayoutParameters);
        lp.Width = 300;
        lp.Gravity = (int)GravityFlags.Right;
        _masterLayout.LayoutParameters = lp;
    }
 }
```

Comment: @Djork,Please review once.